# Getting map using plotly python

Tags: plotly

I want to display some points (longitude, latitude) on a map of Taiwan using plotly library. The problem is where can I find such a map of Taiwan and load it and is there some sample?

Comment: Start here: https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/basemap-maps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have created tutorials for problems like this, you can access it on: https://github.com/SayaliSonawane/Plotly_Offline_Python/tree/master/Satellite%20Map

You can use satellite map in outdoor style to create this type of plot:

```
import plotly
import pandas as pd
from plotly.graph_objs import Scattermapbox,Data,Layout

# Open mapbox account and pass your access token over here
# Mapbox account sign up and access token is free. 
# Mapbox information: https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-access-tokens-work/#rotating-tokens

mapbox_access_token = 'Enter_your_access_token'
data = Data([Scattermapbox(
        lat= dataframe_name['Latitude'],
        lon= dataframe_name['Longitude'],
        # text: provide column which will display hover information
        text = [str(n) for n in dataframe_name['ADR_Line_2']],
        mode='markers',
        marker = dict(color = 'rgb(0, 128, 0)',size=10),  
        hoverinfo='skip'
    ) ]) 



layout = Layout(
        title = "title_for_plot",
        font=dict(family='Courier New, monospace', size=18, color='rgb(0,0,0)'),
        autosize=False,
        hovermode='closest',
        showlegend=False,
        width=1800,
        height=1000,
        mapbox=dict(
            accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
            #width=1415,
            bearing=0,
            pitch=0,
            style = 'outdoors'
        ),
    )                    

plotly.offline.plot({"data":data, "layout":layout},filename = 'taiwan_map.html')
```